# How prevent line breaks in a text area and to stop Jquery from counting line breaks as values

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, keypress, preventdefault

I'm using the following code to send some value from a textarea but first i want to ensure that the Textarea is not empty and then if not empty on keypress "Enter" then send the value to ajax.

The problem is value length counts line breaks and the validation fails. Another is line breaks, How do i prevent line breaks?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) { 
        if ($('.msgInput').val().length < 2){
            alert ('No lol, your message is too short, type some more...')
        } else {
        var Msg = $('#Messageinput').val()

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data: {
                    data:Msg
                },
                url:"../websocket-example-821156/client.php"
            }).done(function(feedback){
                $('#NewMessagesHolder').prepend('<div class="MessageClass    ServerMessage">'+ '<span class="ChatName">Server ('+ time + ')</span>' + ':'+feedback+'</div>');
            })  

            var text = $('.msgInput').val();

            $('.msgInput').val("");
            $('#NewMessagesHolder').prepend('<div class="MessageClass">'+ '<span class="ChatName">' + CookieName + ' ('+ time + ')</span>' + ': '+ text +'</div>')
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: A textarea where you prevent line breaks is nothing more than a regular input.

Comment: You are not consistent. .msgInput and #Messageinput - get it ONCE and reuse: `var Msg = $.trim($('#Messageinput').val());
if(e.which == 13) { 
        if (Msg.length < 2){
        alert ('No lol, your message is too short, type some more...')
        } else {` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.trim`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to remove line breaks for start and end. This will make him at least put two characters. As with single character you would remove the line breaks and left with the character.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S8kkm/)**

```
if ($.trim($('.msgInput').val()).length < 2){
```

> The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including
>   non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the
>   supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of
>   the string, they are preserved, [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {

    var text = $('.msgInput').val().replace(/\r\n/g,'\n').replace(/\n/g,'');

    if(e.which == 13) { 
        if (text.length < 2){
        alert ('No lol, your message is too short, type some more...')
       } else {
        var Msg = $('#Messageinput').val()
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: {data:Msg},
            url:"../websocket-example-821156/client.php"
        }).done(function(feedback){
        $('#NewMessagesHolder').prepend('<div class="MessageClass ServerMessage">'+ '<span class="ChatName">Server ('+ time + ')</span>' + ':'+feedback+'</div>');
    })  

    $('.msgInput').val("")
$('#NewMessagesHolder').prepend('<div class="MessageClass">'+ '<span class="ChatName">' + CookieName + ' ('+ time + ')</span>' + ': '+ text +'</div>')
    }
    } 
});
```